# Non-standard HTTP methods and Apache Http Components

Tags: java, http, apache-httpcomponents

I'm writing an HTTP server using the HttpCore library of [Apache HTTPComponents 4.3](http://hc.apache.org/) (Java).  My server must be able to receive requests that have non-standard HTTP methods (methods other than GET, POST, DELETE, etc).

But when my server receives such a request, it returns a "method not supported" response.  Is there a way to force HTTPComponents to accept non-standard HTTP methods?

Background: I'm working on implementing a WebDAV server, which uses non-standard methods (like MKCOL and PROPFIND).

Comment: Which version of HTTPComponents library are you using? v4+ has much better at handling custom implementations like WebDAV.

Comment: Looks like apache has you covered, found the jackrabbit project http://jackrabbit.apache.org/ I have not used it but it looks like a good start looking

Comment: @r3mus Oops sorry, forgot to include the version.  I'm using version 4.3 of HttpCore.  And I'm not looking for a WebDAV implementation.  I'm writing my own as a personal project.

Comment: I might be misunderstanding. Are you using HttpComponents as a client or as a server?

Comment: No, I got that -- apparently 4+ can handle it though. But that Jackrabbit looks pretty slick too, would save you some trouble.

Comment: @SotiriosDelimanolis As a server.  I'm using HttpComponents to create an HTTP server.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I found the solution, so I will answer my own question. xD

You have to create your own `HttpRequestFactory` implementation, and pass it up the chain.

```
HttpRequestFactory reqFact = new HttpRequestFactory() {
  public HttpRequest newHttpRequest(final RequestLine requestline) throws MethodNotSupportedException {
    return new BasicHttpEntityEnclosingRequest(requestline);
  }

  public HttpRequest newHttpRequest(final String method, final String uri) throws MethodNotSupportedException {
    return new BasicHttpEntityEnclosingRequest(method, uri);
  }
};
HttpMessageParserFactory<HttpRequest> parserFact = new DefaultHttpRequestParserFactory(null, reqFact);
HttpConnectionFactory<DefaultBHttpServerConnection> connFact = new DefaultBHttpServerConnectionFactory(null, parserFact, null)
```

The implementation that HttpComponents uses by default throws a `MethodNotSupportedException` if a non-standard HTTP method is found.  The source code for the default implementation can be found here:

http://hc.apache.org/httpcomponents-core-4.3.x/httpcore/xref/org/apache/http/impl/DefaultHttpRequestFactory.html